# How to identify things in bags?

Tags: conv-neural-network, resnet, mobilenet

Is there any way to identify the items in the bag?
[images like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhRry.jpg)

I have tried ResNet50 and MobileNetv1,They all identified it as a bag rather than the contents.Maybe I should use some data augmentation methods?

This is my first question here, If anything wrong please tell me.
Thanks very much!